# get_permalink not working in WordPress template file

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I an newbie in PHP and I have the following in a template file.

```
$url = get_permalink(get_page_by_title('Main'));
```

But the above line gives me an error ..

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_permalink() in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\handleLogin.php
```

I tried including the file `link-template` at the top by using the below line but it doesn't find the file either.

```
include_once 'wp-includes/link-template.php';
```

I googled but everyone seems to have it working .. those who complained were having typos in the function name which are not my cases.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'd start [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/#source-code).

Comment: How and where are you using your `handleLogin.php` file? Is it a page template, a template part, etc?

Comment: handleLogin.php is just a plain php file ...not a page template or a template part.

Comment: @dcreight I used the same page but it gives me this error even though the function is available since v1 in WordPress

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old post. But posting if anyone comes looking for answers like me.

After requiring, **wp-load.php** add below,

```
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-rewrite.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/link-template.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-post.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/category-template.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/taxonomy.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/l10n.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php';
```